# Run a script at logoff on XP Home?

Tags: windows-xp, script, group-policy

Is this possible without having a process running continuously, listening for `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` or similar? (or worse still, [loading a DLL into the Winlogon process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

(Also unacceptable: write a script / program that does what you want, then logs off, and require the user to only use this program to log off, rather than Start -> Log Off or various other normal methods)

It's easy on XP Pro with Group Policy but I don't think that works on XP Home even if you "install" the group policy editor.

Comment: Have you tried out with installing `GPEDIT` on XP Home? If not then give a try to it.

Comment: See [velocityreviews](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t476325-logon-logoff-scripts-is-xp-home.html) and [this](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/windows-xp-home-edition-logoff-script/10080.html). May be they will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this Stack Overflow question may be your best bet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/how-to-run-my-program-on-before-logout-on-windows-xp

This Techguy.org thread also goes into more options in more detail: http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/728218-solved-logoff-script-windows-xp.html

The basic approaches are to either use WMI to listen for or hook Win32_ComputerShutdownEvent or to have something running (possibly hidden) that Windows will send a shutdown message to, written in something that lets you trap the reason for closing.

Comment: But I specifically said I didn't want to keep a process running.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if you can set up a hook that will launch an executable, but I doubt it. Since it seems that some variation of this is available in XP Pro and nobody's come up with an XP Home solution that doesn't require a process in the past 10+ years, it seems to me that your options include A) change OS or B) have something running. Expecting innovation for a sunsetted consumer product seems unpromising.

Comment: I realize it's a difficult question. That's why I put a bounty on it :)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Task Scheduler has a trigger "On disconnect from user session".

I don't remember if the feature was available on Windows XP home though. If not you might find a good event-log entry to trigger the task instead (some service stopping for example).

Comment: "On disconnect from user session" isn't even available on XP Pro. I'll investigate event triggers.

Comment: It was a good idea, but unfortunately `eventtriggers.exe` is not present on XP home, and doesn't work if you copy it across.

Comment: It's quite a hack, but you could try replacing C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe with your executable which will call the original in sequence with identical commandline... kind of tricky but I'm also scraping the bottom of "the hat of tricks" by now...

Comment: Are you implying that all logoffs / shutdowns go via `shutdown.exe`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I assume. (I know that's dangerous) But it would not surprise me (30K is not nothing)

Comment: I checked it out. shutdown.exe is just a wrapper around the ExitWindowsEx function defined in User32.dll. shutdown.exe seems to be seldom used. Sorry for pointing to a dead end.